# This undefined in imported arrow function react

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope, this, arrow-functions

this is the main React component:

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this)
    init()
  }
  // react render
  render() {
    return (
      <div ref={ref => (this.mount = ref)} />
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

And in anotther file, i have this function which i import in App.js:

```
var init = () => {
    console.log(this)
    // Initiates the entire env

    // Initiate clock
    this.clock = new THREE.Clock()
    ...
    // Add event listener in case window resizes
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.onWindowResize, false)
    ...

}
```

It is to my understanding that an arrow function does not have its own scope/this so that it gets the this of the enclosing scope. 
Why does it not work in this example? The first print, in the *App* component prints right and the next print gets undefined.

This is how the two prints look like: [image]

Comment: What is the context where `init` is?

Comment: *And in anotther file* Since `this` is inherited lexically, the scope in which `init` is declared in that other file must not have a calling context either. `console.log(this); var init = () => {` will show you `undefined` as well.

Comment: @VLAZ it's just another file, *main.js* where i declared a bunch of functions so that i won't clogg  App.js file. I export them with *export { init, animate };* and import them like this *import { init, animate } from './js/main'*

Comment: @Mike if it's another file, then the context is different. If it's different, then it's not `App`. As you yourself said - the arrow function would use the enclosing context and in the latter case, there is none.

Comment: @VLAZ, ok, and is there any import method to achieve this result without having to put them all in the same file? Coming from python this is very confusing

Comment: `import` doesn't alter the context. You can use normal functions that will dynamically get the `this` value when executed or even set it via `.bind`, `.call` or `.apply`. I'm not clear what your goal is but these are the normal mechanisms. Given that the code is not part of the `App` class, I'd even say you should probably just not use `this` but do something like `ley myApp = new App()` and then use `myApp` (or whatever you want to call the variable) instead of `this`.